# Unhiding class elements one by one via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got HTML classes like

```
<path class="paths" fill="gainsboro" d="M644 1780c13...>
<path class="paths" fill="#E5E6E5" d="M759 2308c12,-10...>
<path class="paths" fill="#E0F3EC" d="M1340 1848c-3,9 5,6...>
```

CSS default value

```
.paths {display:none;}
```

JS

```
window.onload="show()";
function show(){
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(".paths");
  for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++){
  a[i].style.display="";
  }
}
```

With javascript I am trying to unhide all elements one by one to create animation. As you can see, my js code doesn't work and after few hours of trying a decided to ask because I am lost.

EDIT: I forgot to append my project -> https://codepen.io/r8w9/pen/ZxePML

Comment: Please add a working snippet.

Comment: Do you expect a `for` loop to have a perceptible delay?

Comment: @vibhor1997a Codepen appended.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't care about timing and delay for now.

Comment: `unhide all elements one by one to create animation` - it seems you do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Of course I want to create animation but now I am solving that my code doesn't work at all. Adding delays to create an animation is a detail

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXpRjQ this looks amazing!

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! It's because you helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I would do:

1. add the onload function as an anonymous function, because it doesn't
   need a name
2. put the elements in a real array to have access to
   `.shift()`
3. set an interval to perform the unhiding on a timed basis
4. inside the timed function: remove and get the first element from the
   array using `.shift()`
5. set the elements display to `initial`(it's
   default, because it could be other than `block`)
6. if the array is
   empty remove the interval

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var paths = document.querySelectorAll(".paths");
  var hidden = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) hidden.push(paths[i]);
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    hidden.shift().style.display = "initial";
    if (hidden.length == 0) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 200);
}
```

```css
.paths {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="paths">A</span><span class="paths">A</span><span class="paths">A</span><span class="paths">A</span>
```

(I used `<span>`, so something is visibly happening)

**EDIT** For older browsers (without arrow functions support):

```js
var hidden = [];
var interval;
window.onload = function() {
  var paths = document.querySelectorAll(".paths");
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) hidden.push(paths[i]);
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    hidden.shift().style.display = "initial";
    if (hidden.length == 0) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 200);
}
```

```css
.paths {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="paths">A</span><span class="paths">A</span><span class="paths">A</span><span class="paths">A</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Why use `span` when the question is using `paths`? If the change of the HTML element is needed isn't that the answer?

Comment: I used `<span>` because it is irrelevant and the incomplete `<path>` elements weren't visible

Comment: Sebastian. I don't have enough reputation to give you +1 so don't think that I am ingrateful. Btw your code is amazing. I have to study it because when I take a look it's new for me. For example it looks like you are missing curly brackets right after the for loop plus I see some => arrow and it is something new for me :d

Comment: Single line expressions don't need their own `{}` block. The `=>` is part of an arrow function, which are a very short way to create functions and in addition have a few benefits over normal functions. You can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: Sebastian I found out that your code doesn't work in IE :/

Comment: because IE is old, but I will add a version for old browsers if you need it

Comment: Sebastian, your rework is excellent. I tried some code rewrite too. You can check it out https://codepen.io/r8w9/pen/EEWBLv

Comment: works perfectly, but you don't need to name the function `foo()` if you input it directly as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload=show();
function show(){
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(".paths");
  for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++){
  
  a[i].classList.remove("paths");
  }
}
```

```css
.paths {display:none;}
Because class still exist in <path> element that's why it's not show <path> content. Best approach is to remove class to show <path>
```

```html
<path class="paths" fill="gainsboro" d="M644 1780c13...">a</path>
<path class="paths" fill="#E5E6E5" d="M759 2308c12,-10...">b</path>
<path class="paths" fill="#E0F3EC" d="M1340 1848c-3,9 5,6...">c</path>
```

Comment: sorry I got late to answer rate if you like

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will also helps you.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("paths");
console.log(elements)
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
(function(i){

    window.setTimeout(function(){
    elements[i].style.display="block";
    }, i * 300);

  }(i));
}
```

```css
.paths {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<svg height="400" width="450">
<path class="paths" id="lineAB" d="M 100 350 l 150 -300" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <path class="paths" id="lineBC" d="M 250 50 l 150 300" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <path class="paths" d="M 175 200 l 150 0" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <path class="paths" d="M 100 350 q 150 -300 300 0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
</svg>
```